# Locking a range instead using of a offset

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new here. Just want to ask how to edit the code below if I want to lock cells in E3:F3 whenever cell D3 is empty, lock E4:F4 if D4 is empty so on... Thank you in advance.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Dim aCell As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Range("D3:D502"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect ""
        For Each aCell In Range("D3:D502")
            If Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) = 0 Then _
            aCell.Offset(, 1).Locked = True Else _
            aCell.Offset(, 1).Locked = False
        Next
        ActiveSheet.Protect ""
    End If
Letscontinue:
     Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
Whoa:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

I'd like to lock a range of cell, but the code is locking the cell after my active cell

Comment: You may try `UNION()` method like `Union(aCell.Offset(, 1),aCell.Offset(, 2)).Locked = True`.

Comment: Thank you, sorry but what I mean is to lock E3:AO3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- reduce the looping range to save time
- update `Locked` with a code line
- `Resize(1, 2)` to expand the range (a cell) to `1 row x 2 columns`

Please try

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    Dim aCell As Range, c As Range
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set c = Intersect(Range("D3:D502"), Target)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect ""
        For Each aCell In c
            aCell.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 2).Locked = (Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) = 0)
        Next
        ActiveSheet.Protect ""
    End If
Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Please refers to Microsoft document.

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)